# Is android constantly producing errors?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, logcat

In the Android catlog in IntelliJ IDEA, there is a filter for "Errors." Connecting my Android phone via USB, I saw that whenever I made an action, like going through menus, opening or closing apps, or any action made in the app that I'm designing, the LogCat would spew lines of error.

Most of them are ActivityThread Errors, such as

```
12-31 19:58:57.149: ERROR/ActivityThread(16017): >>> handling: 124
12-31 19:59:07.819: ERROR/ActivityThread(28993): >>> handling: 124
12-31 19:59:11.270: ERROR/ActivityThread(273): >>> handling: 113
12-31 19:59:11.290: ERROR/ActivityThread(273): >>> handling: 114
12-31 19:59:11.300: ERROR/ActivityThread(273): >>> handling: 115
12-31 19:59:11.470: ERROR/ActivityThread(273): >>> handling: 116
12-31 19:59:11.490: ERROR/ActivityThread(273): >>> handling: 119
```

The second most common are audio errors (note that my phone is on silent)

```
12-31 19:56:18.760: ERROR/AudioPolicyManagerBase(97): getDeviceForStrategy() from cache strategy 0, device 2
12-31 19:56:18.760: ERROR/AudioPolicyManagerBase(97): getNewDevice() selected device 2
12-31 19:56:18.760: ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(97): Routing audio to Speakerphone
12-31 19:56:18.760: ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(97): [FM]sndDevice(6) mCurSndDevice(6) mFM(0)
12-31 19:56:18.760: ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(97): rpc_snd_set_volume(28, 0, 7)
```

One of my errors involved my USB, although I believe it's because it disconnected when I restarted the app during debug.

```
12-31 19:43:51.170: ERROR/Tethering(150): active iface (usb0) reported as added, ignoring
```

Why do all these errors happen? Is Android perpetually causing errors and fixing them? Is there a fundamental flaw in Androids structure, that keeps producing these errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do all these errors happen?

None of those messages should be logged at error severity, based on my reading of the Android source code. They are all logged at informational or verbose severity, not error.

I'd first examine LogCat outside of IntelliJ, such as via the `monitor` program from your SDK's `tools/` directory, and its copy of DDMS. If you see things logged at appropriate levels there, then IntelliJ perhaps has a bug in how it is displaying these messages to you.

Otherwise, if I had to guess, whoever made your ROM screwed something up, escalating all of these things to error severity. If this is a ROM mod, complain to the mod makers. If this is a production ROM, complain to your device manufacturer.